# Updating/Inserting Oracle table from csv data file

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sql-update, upsert

I am still learning Oracle SQL, and I've been trying to find the best way to update/insert records in an OracleSQL table with the data from a CSV file.

So far, I've figured out how to load the csv into a temporary table using External Tables in Oracle, but I'm having difficulty finding a detailed guide on how to update/insert (UPSERT) the loaded data into an existing table.

What is the best way to do this, when I have 30+ fields in the table? For example, is it best to read the csv line by line with something like pandas and update each record one by one, or is it best to do it with a sql script using something like a merge statement? Not all records in the csv have a value for the primary key, in which case I need to insert rather than update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using MERGE with Python cx_Oracle's `executemany()` is one option. See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a `MERGE`, indeed.

Data from external table would then be used to

- update values in existing rows
- create new rows in the target table

---

Pandas and row-by-row processing? I wouldn't do that. If you already have a powerful database, then use its capabilities. Row-by-row is usually slow-by-slow and there's rarely some benefit in doing it that way.

Comment: MERGE ftw! Executing data manipulation in the database will always be more performative than moving it in and out of the database

Comment: Oracle has a very good utility called SqlLoader to parse and fast-load text files (fixed format, or delimited: CSV Tab separated, etc.); have you considered?